# SQLException: UCAExc:::5.0.0 row column count mismatch

Tags: java, mysql, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

I have a project created by java code, and a database that has two tables (table1 and table2)
looks like this:

```
-------table1--------

Name      |  Ref
__________|__________
    A     |  100
    B     |  200
__________|__________

and 

-------table2--------

Name      |  Q
__________|__________
    A     |  12
    B     |  10
    A     |  14
__________|__________
```

I try create a SQL query to get this result:

```
Name      |  Ref    |  SUM(Q)
__________|_________|__________
    A     |  100    |   26
    B     |  200    |   10
__________|_________|__________
```

I wrote this query

```
query ="SELECT table1.Name,table1.Ref FROM table1 WHERE table1.Name=(SELECT table2.Name,SUM(table2.Q) FROM table2 GROUP BY table2.Name)";
```

but my code not working and I'm getting this error:

```
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::5.0.0 row column count mismatch
```

any suggestions to correct my query code?

Comment: **Please do not change your question after it has been answered.** Instead please ask *another question* if you need help with something else.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
SELECT table1.Name,table1.Ref 
  FROM table1 
 WHERE table1.Name IN (SELECT table2.Name FROM table2)
```

Your subquery has two problems.

1. It returns more than one column, so it's not suitable for matching with `=` or `IN`.
2. It may return more than one row, so it's not suitable for matching with `=`.

Comment: but I need to show a result of  ```SUM(table2.Q)``` how can I do it ??

Comment: Please ask another question. And, in the question please show some sample data and desired results from that sample data.

Comment: sorry I think the pbm in my code java not in query, I will try to fix it